# Payment in Botman

Tags: laravel, telegram, telegram-bot, payment, botman

I am making a telegram bot that provides paid advanced access. I use the botman studio library.

There was a problem getting a response from telegrams "PreCheckoutQuery".

I went the following way:

**1. Created a hierarchy of dialogs using buttons**

*Main menu (MainConversation)

**some sub-menu

***some sub-sub-menu

***etc

*Payment (PaymentConversation)

*Help (HelpConversation)

**2. I navigate through the menu sections using switch-case and the ask method:**

```
$this->ask('some text', function (Answer $answer)
    switch ($answer->getText()) {
        case 'some function':
            $this->bot->startConversation(new SomeConversation());
            break;
        case 'Payment':
            $this->bot->startConversation(new PaymentConversation());
            break;
        case 'Help':
            $this->bot->startConversation(new HelpConversation());
    }
}, $this->keyboard());
```

**3. Inside PaymentConversation this code:**

```
public function invoice()
{
    $invoice = [
        'title' => 'asdf',
        'description' => 'asdf',
        'payload' => 'asdf',
        'provider_token' => 'some token',
        'currency' => 'USD',
        'prices' => json_encode(array(array(
            'label' => 'asdf',
            'amount' => 100000
        )))
    ];
$this->bot->sendRequest('sendInvoice', $invoice);
}
```

After sendRequest, the bot sends an invoice to which the user must respond. After the payment information is filled in, telegram sends an update "pre_checkout_query" to which I must answer using the answerPreCheckoutQuery method ([more details](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answerprecheckoutquery))
I don't understand how to properly force botman update to listen from telegrams inside the dialog.

At first I had the idea to just make a middleware that would track the PreCheckoutQuery in IncomingMessage, but I ran into the fact that the class does not understand this request and created a separate TelegramPreCheckoutQueryDriver that handles such messages.
Now I can confirm the payment in the intermediary, but this greatly limits my actions. I would like to do this as part of a dialogue.

I see this algorithm:

1. User clicked the Payments button
2. The PaymentConversation dialog has started
3. An invoice has been sent to the user
4. The user fills in payment details and clicks pay
5. Bot receives message with PreCheckoutQuery
6. Bot returns pre_checkout_query_id value
7. Bot sends answerPreCheckoutQuery
8. The bot receives payment confirmation and writes information about it to the database
9. The bot launches the MainConversation dialog

**I would be very grateful for any help! Thank you!**

Comment: Almost 2 years and no answer, same issue here. 